# Expandable Recycler view search view not working

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

This is filter method of my recyclerview filterable code.

```
     @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
                String charString = charSequence.toString();
                if (charString.isEmpty()) {
                    mParentItemList = mOriginalList;
                } else {
                    List<ParentListItem> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (ParentListItem row : mParentItemList) {

                        // name match condition. this might differ depending on your requirement
                        // here we are looking for name or phone number match
                        for (Object childListItem : row.getChildItemList()) {
                            if (((Help) childListItem).getName().toLowerCase().contains(charString.toLowerCase())) {
                                filteredList.add(row);
                            }
                        }

//                        if (row.getName().toLowerCase().contains(charString.toLowerCase()) || row.getPhone().contains(charSequence)) {
//                            filteredList.add(row);
//                        }
                    }

                    mParentItemList = filteredList;
                }

                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                filterResults.values = mParentItemList;
                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
                mParentItemList = (ArrayList<ParentListItem>) filterResults.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
    }
```

I am getting filtered list in mParentList variable properly but when i am calling notifydatasetchanged() recyclerview not updating and UI is not updating.

Comment: have you solved it? How have you implemented `mOriginalList`?